# Windows. How set GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1

Tags: git, github-actions, fastlane

Now I have `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0` . And if I do `git clone https://github.com/some/non-existing-repo` - will fail without prompting for username & password. I need set `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1`. But I can't find, how can I do it.

In `fastlane` when I try run build, I need clone repo with sertificates. I get this:

[image]

Comment: How did you set GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 to start with? It sounds like this is just an environment variable, so you can set it in any of the ways you'd normally set an environment variable in Windows. (Where do GitHub actions come in here? Is this running *within* a GHA, or is it on your local machine? We really need more information.)

Comment: I run `fastlane` to build progect, but when  `Cloning remote git repo` started I get `No such file or directory - GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone 'git@bitbucket.org:folder/folder.git' 'C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Temp/d0000000-1234-dfrpo' . So, I decided that I get this message because I added SSH-key for repo and now I need   username & password

Comment: Please edit your question (rather than just adding comments) to provide *much* more information about what you're trying to do and the environment in which you're trying to do it.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet, I added screen

Comment: A screenshot isn't the same as providing details about the context etc. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question - hopefully after you've done so, someone else will be able to help you...